# Value-at-Risk formula when using skewed-t distribution

Tags: value-at-risk

I am trying to find a formula for the skewed-t VaR. For example the VaR formula for a t-distribution is

$$
\sqrt{\frac{df-2}{df}} \times \Sigma{t} \times \mbox{quantitle}(t-\mbox{dist}, 0.01) + \mu
$$

(Please excuse the messy formula & the sigma(t) denotes a GARCH model)

However I am struggling to do the same for a skewed-t distribution

I am using the `rugarch` package in R and I am struggling to find out which version of the skewed-t distribution is being used. I went to the fGarch pdf and downloaded the reference [ON BAYESIAN MODELLING OF FAT TAILS AND SKEWNESS](http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=3396) by C. Fernandez et al., but my lack of Bayesian knowledge means the pdf it says is the Skew-Student is not helping perhaps as much as it should.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have $\LaTeX$-ified your formula. Please make sure it is correct.

Comment: Which Skewed-t Distribution are you using? there are many representations....

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found in the following paper (*section 2.3 Distribution and quantile functions of a skewed distribution*):

> Lambert and Laurent, 2002
>   Lambert, P., Laurent, S., 2002. Modeling skewness dynamics in series of financial data using skewed location-scale distributions. Working Paper, Université Catholique de Louvain and Université de Liège.

And I summarize it in the following :

The quantile function $skst_{\alpha,v,\xi}$ of a *non standardized* skewed-Student density (Fernandez and Steel
(1998)) is given by :
$$
skst_{\alpha,v,\xi}= \frac{1}{\xi}st_{\alpha,v}\left[ \frac{\alpha}{2}(1+\xi^2)\right]  \qquad \text{if} \qquad \alpha < \frac{1}{1+\xi^2}
$$

or :

$$
skst_{\alpha,v,\xi}= -\xi st_{\alpha,v}\left[ \frac{1-\alpha}{2}(1+\xi^{-2})\right]  \qquad \text{if} \qquad \alpha \geq \frac{1}{1+\xi^2}
$$

where $\xi$ is the asymmetry coefficient, $v$ the degree of freedom and $\alpha $ is the quantile probability. $st_{\alpha,v}$ is the quantile function of the (unit variance) Student-t density.

> Then the VaR for long position is given by $μ_{t} +
> > skst_{\alpha,v,\xi}\sigma_{t}$ with $skst_{\alpha,v,\xi}$ being the
>   left quantile at $\alpha$% for the skewed-Student distribution with
>   $v$ degrees of freedom and asymmetry coefficient $\xi$;$μ_{t}$ is the conditional  mean process.

If you are interested in application, the g@rch package by S.Laurent in Ox programming language implements this computation (this answer is also based on its documentation).